# Shell Script: How to repeat last query if an unexpected value is typed by the user?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

In many scripts which I write, I'm using very specific `if statements` and the user which is running the script is given 2 or more options to select from, like this example portion from one of my scripts:

```
read -r -p "How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon " DMN
if [[ "$DMN" = [Xx] ]];        
  then
    DMNMODE="xinetd"
    cat << EOF > $XINETDFILE
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = $NRPEPORT
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = $NGUSER 
        group           = $NGGROUP
        server          = /usr/sbin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c $NRPECFG --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 $NAGIOSSRV
}
EOF
    $XINETDSVC restart
elif [[ "$DMN" = [Dd] ]];
    then 
    chkconfig nrpe on ; $NRPESVC start
    DMNMODE="daemon"
fi
```

If the user types one of the expected values then everything is okay and the script works as expected, but if there's a typo in one of the answers and the script gets a value it doesn't know then the script exits.
I want to make sure that the user doesn't get kicked out of the script in case of a typo... I was thinking that if a typo is inserted then the user is asked the last question again.
I know it can be achieved by using `Case` but I'm looking for a better solution, can you please assist me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that the `select` built-in is useful for:

```
select DMN in 'Xinetd' 'Standalone Daemon'; do
    if [[ "$DMN" = [Xx] ]]; then
        ....
        break
    elif [[ "$DMN" = [Dd] ]]; then
         ...
         break
    fi
done
```

Then just check the value of `DMN` and break when you have a valid value, falling off the end of the loop will automatically prompt again.

Comment: That's exactly the more sophisticated way I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you need:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
read -r -p "How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon " DMN
if [[ "$DMN" = [Xx] ]];        
  then
    DMNMODE="xinetd"
    cat << EOF > $XINETDFILE
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = $NRPEPORT
        socket_type     = stream
        wait            = no
        user            = $NGUSER 
        group           = $NGGROUP
        server          = /usr/sbin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c $NRPECFG --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = 127.0.0.1 $NAGIOSSRV
}
EOF
    $XINETDSVC restart
    break
elif [[ "$DMN" = [Dd] ]];
    then 
    chkconfig nrpe on ; $NRPESVC start
    DMNMODE="daemon"
    break
else
    continue
fi
done
```

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: it's an infinite while loop, as long as user enters the expected values, the script does what is supposed to be done and breaks from the loop. If user gives anything else than the expected values, the script will continue with the question ("How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon?...") to the user.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like that's exactly what I need, is this the most sophisticated way to handle these situations?

Comment: It's not sophisticated. Since you need to repeat the question to the user as long as he enters the wrong value, the loop should be infinite. If proper values are entered, it does the thing and comes out immediately. It's definitely not complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop around your if statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

success=0
while [ $success -lt 1 ]; do
    read -r -p "How would you like to configure the NRPE daemon? [X]inetd / Standalone [D]aemon " DMN
    if [[ "$DMN" = [Xx] ]];
      then
            echo "option 1"
            success=1
    elif [[ "$DMN" = [Dd] ]];
      then
            echo "option 2"
            success=1
    fi
done
```